# How to put QImage with gray background inside QIcon?

Tags: c++, qt, qimage, qicon

I'm doing:

```
QIcon(QPixmap::fromImage(img));
```

and then putting it to `QToolButton` with `setIcon` and `setIconSize`

I need to have my `img` surrounded with gray color inside this icon - how can I implement this?

alike there: [image]

Comment: Hello Heather,

Can you put an image of how you want it to look like exactly.?

Comment: @PRIME with pleasure, added to question

Comment: @Heather did you try `toolButton->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(190, 190, 190)");` and then set your Icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting a Stylesheet should do the job for you..

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        QApplication a(argc, argv);
        QToolButton b;
        b.setStyleSheet("QToolButton { background-color: grey }");  
        QImage img("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\Icon.png");
        b.setIcon( QPixmap::fromImage(img) );
        b.show();
        a.exec();
    }
```

Try this out.
You can also play around with the QPalette of the button, that also provides you a very fine control over the way you want your widgets to look.

Comment: thanks, important that I use setIconSize and setMinimumSize to make it as I want

Comment: Heather, That is not the right way to go for it.
Shrinking the icon size below the minimum possible size changes the way it look but that is not certain to look the correct way on different platforms.
It may not look consistent on cross platform applications.

Comment: That is a bit complicated now :)

The simplest way to go for it is to create your own class inheriting from the QToolButton and override the PaintEvent and then manually place the pixmap of the icon where ever you want.

Stylesheets will not help you in achieving this this.